# Android Context Action Bar (CAB) on GridView and onClickListener

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have GridView with images and I am using CAB for multiple selection of images in grid

```
 gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
 gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() { .... }
```

CAB is activated on long click. But on clicking image I want to start another one activity. If I implement setOnClickListener in adapter, CAB activation stops working and onClick is always called. Even if I try to make long click

How to keep my onClickListener and CAB activation on long click?

Comment: Have the same problem but with OnItemLongClickListener. How do I keep Android invoking my OnItemLongClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

Just set mGridView.setOnItemClickListener for the single-click and mGridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener for the long-click CAB.

Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB